# Best practice when developing an RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently creating an application. It's relatively simple, lets say for now it only contains users & posts

What I am trying to do is display basically a blog with a new post form at the top in case the signed in user is admin.

I have two options:

I can use an index for posts and keep it all within the posts controller. I could add a form to the index.html.erb which checks for admin attributes.

However, I will most likely use the index functionality later on in other parts of the app.

Second option would be to create a static page called blog and render the form view and all posts.

Both should be possible, but what is the "rails way"? Or is there no best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers should be RESTful, and should be appropriately named for the resources they manipulate.

The `index` action of your `PostsController` should have one purpose ... providing appropriate information relating to all of the posts to its view. The exact output of this could change within the view depending on whether you're logged in as an admin or not, but essentially the role of that action should be restricted to that function.

I would advise you to take a look at the [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and think about how you could use that to authenticate users, providing appropriate page content to admins and normal users alike.